# How to open chrome in a new session in command line without having to confirm on an initial pop up window?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I try to use chrome in a new session with the following command.

```
'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'  --user-data-dir="$tmpdir"
```

But it pops up a window like this
[image]

Is there a way to prevent this pop up window from showing up? Or is there a better way to open chrome in a new session?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my system, it's opening new window each time I execute the command `'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'  --user-data-dir="$tmpdir"`
 I don't understand what you mean by a new session. Is it a new window of chrome or a new window with a new account.
Also, please see if this post resolves your issue
https://askubuntu.com/questions/35392/how-to-launch-a-new-instance-of-google-chrome-from-the-command-line

Comment: My question is to supress the popup window shown in my original post.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't face such an issue while running the command, so not able to help. Now I am also confused about why this popup is showing in your system but not in mine. Let's see if someone can provide answer for this.